# Bind an array of ids to an event handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var fields = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Profession", "Address", "City", "State", "Phone", "Email", "Message"];
$.each(fields, function()
{
    var $this = $("#" + this);
    $this.bind("focus", function()
    {
        //
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to bind an event method to the array ? Something like this :

```
$.each(fields).bind("focus", function()
{
    //
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
var fields = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Profession", "Address", "City", "State", "Phone", "Email", "Message"];
fields = "#" + fields.join(", #");
$(fields).bind("focus", function()
{
    //Your function
});
```

But's it's better to give all the elements a class and bind like this:

```
$(".focusDoFunc").bind("focus", function()
{
    //Your function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just give all those elements the same class and do:

```
$('.classname').bind("focus", function()
{
    //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all those element a common class name "formFields" and use `delegate` to attach event handler at the form level. That way you dont have to attach event handler to each of the elements within the form

```
$("formSelector").delegate(".formFields", "focus", function(){
    //Here do your stuff
});
```

If you want to have `focus` event attached to all elements within the form then you don't even  need to add a class we can use `input`, `select` and `textarea` selector. Just do this

```
$("formSelector").delegate("input, select, textarea", "focus", function(){
    //Here do your stuff
});
```